# javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Element type "role"

Tags: java, postgresql, ubuntu, vps, tomcat10

help me, I have a problem when deploying a Java web application with PostgresQL using Tomcat on VPS server

org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.getUserDatabase Exception looking up UserDatabase under key [UserDatabase]
javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 30; Element type "role" must be followed by ei

result status true or successfull deploying war using tomcat and postgresql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add additional details to reproduce the issue. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what could be the cause of the issue. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).